# Oracle Trim RegEx

Tags: oracle, trim

I am trying to execute a join between two tables in Oracle where the column in one of the tables is a string and number in the other.

I need to perform some sort of trim function the string version because it is an 8 character field and will lead with `0`s in cases where the number is less than 8 digits.

For example, `123 = '00000123'`. How can I get the string `'00000123'` to equal `'123'` regardless of the number of leading `0`s.

Thanks!!

Comment: You might want to look at the data and the execution plan to see if it's better convert the string to a number, or the number to a zero-padded string, to minimise the overhead and make the best use of any indexes etc. when comparing the column values. With a lot of data or a query you'll run a lot, it may be worth adding a an indexed virtual column or a function-based index to one of the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_number` conversion function:

```
SELECT to_number('00000123')
FROM dual;

| TO_NUMBER('00000123') |
|-----------------------|
|                   123 |
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1792d/18

Comment: Wow. That simple, huh?!

Thanks!!